# The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time

Tags: cors, asp.net-core-webapi

im getting warning error saying

> "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService|The CORS
>   protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and
>   credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing
>   individual origins if credentials needs to be supported."

code 
controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MedPlusController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
               services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

                services.AddCors(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials());
                });

                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            }


            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

                app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

                app.UseMvc();
            }
```

Comment: The error tells you the problem and the solution, where are you stuck?

Comment: i think i need to remove - .AllowCredentials());shall i remove allow credentals?

Comment: What happens if you try that?

Answer (score 3):

If you implement authentication, change `AllowAnyOrigin` to `WithOrigins` like

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });
```

If you would not use authenticaiton, you could remove `.AllowCredentials()` directly.

Refer [Set the allowed origins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2#set-the-allowed-origins)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example Startup.cs file an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API that supports CORS requests from any origin with credentials:

```
 app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
            .AllowCredentials());
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread, but...
you have used `UseCors` twice in your code. Once in startup.cs, in Configure method, second time in your controller class, using decorator.

Not sure it this is the solution for you, but in my case removing decorator helped. Maybe there is kind of a conflict and some default values are applied when UseCors is called twice, I'm not that skillful to track it in source code. But, it helped in my situation.

I found (and fixed) the issue when writing api in .net 6.